# JMeter Include controller

Tags: jmeter

First script

```
Thread-1
 |--Http Sampler
 |--Include Controller <second script>
```

Second script

```
TestPlan
|--Thread-2
|    |--Http Sampler
|--Thread-3
     |--Http Sampler
```

I run the first script which does few steps and uses include controller to call the next script. I need the second script Thread groups (Thread-2 and Thread-3) run simultaneously and not consecutively. 
I understand the thread run concurrently by default. But when I execute my code i see:

- Thread-1 successful
- Thread-2 successful
- Execution never gets to thread-3

Can you please help me? I want to know how to run the second script's thread group simultaneously?

Comment: Are "First script" and "Second script" separate Test Plans? And is "Thread-1" a Thread Group? Please try to stick to the JMeter wording.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are misusing IncludeController, you need to use Test Fragment element in the included test plan (second script)

Answer (score 2):

- First and second script are separate test plans.
- First Test Plan contains one thread, which contains a include controller to call the second script or the second Test plan
- Second test plan contains 2 thread groups

Solution:

- In both the Test Plan untick "Run threads consecutively"
- In the second test plan tick "Delayed thread creation" - this means that the memory requirements are proportional to the number of concurrent active threads, rather than the total thread count
- Threads in JMeter run simultaneously by default.

Understand the difference between concurrency and simultaneous. Here is a helpful link: [How to generate Concurrent User load in Jmeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10190455/how-to-generate-concurrent-user-load-in-jmeter)